# I can't open firefox browser using the code. I have successfully done opening browser chrome & IE

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code in Eclipse :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //selenim code-
        //create driver object Firefox browser
        //we will strictly implement methods of webdriver
        //geckodriver.exe 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Software Testing\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Error Shown:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
at Demo1.main(Demo1.java:17)
```

Comment: Is that the full error? It just seems like a partial stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, this is the full error shown in eclipse